# Replace a character of a string in JS

Tags: javascript

i have a function of downloading excel file. two of the headers shipping addressline1 and 2 can contain character ",". which i want to be replaced by " ". i tried using 
replace(/,/g,' ')
but doesnt work.

```
for(i=0;i<columns.length;i++){
                if(indexesNotToInclude.indexOf(i)>=0){continue;}
                if(firstColumn){
                    firstColumn=false;
                }
                else{
                    csvString += ",";
                }

                console.log(columns[i].name+":"+item[columns[i].name]);
                csvString += item[columns[i].name];
                if([columns[i].name]=='ShippingAddressLine1'||[columns[i].name]=='ShippingAddressLine2')
                {

                    csvString += (item[columns[i].name]).replace(/,/g,' ');
                }
            }
            csvString += "\r\n";
```

Comment: your try looks correct. if you `console.log(item[columns[i].name])`  before doing the replace, do you see the coma ?

Comment: then the replace should work (as this jsfildle demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/grucgahh/)
Can you provide the content of `columns` and `item` so we can try with your real data ?

Comment: SHIPPINGADDRESSLINE1 523 Nana thakor vada junior masjid paase., anand, Gujarat, 388205 
SHIPPINGADDRESSLINE2 Anand GJ IN 388205 9723948144 Delhivery 383510003430 Prepaid PayU Delivered

Comment: hmmm, you'd better edit your question and use a script snippets... This is not helpful

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo of replacing comma character with an empty string:

```
var mystring = "this,is,a,test"  
console.log("Before: " + mystring);
mystring = mystring.split(',').join(' ');
console.log("After: " + mystring);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/37tfd7he/)

Comment: For someone unexperienced with regex, regex approach is totally unclear, while the other approach is clear even you do not know javascript (you understand what is going on).

Comment: then, as other have pointed out in the comments to the question, the problem is not in splitting, but somwhere else. As you will not provide the data (columns, item, ...) or an example with dummy data, there is not much we can do.

Comment: SHIPPINGADDRESSLINE1   523 Nana thakor vada junior masjid paase., anand, Gujarat, 388205  

SHIPPINGADDRESSLINE2 Anand GJ IN 388205 9723948144 Delhivery 383510003430 Prepaid PayU Delivered